# SharePoint Content Database issue

Tags: database

I have 3 Databases for our SharePoint environment, however when I run power shell script to show my content database its only show the 2, and when I go to Manage my content database from CA I can see the error status on missing database. can you please help?

regards

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does "WSS_Content" still exist on the SQL Server or do you want to remove it from the list in Central Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking wss_content should tell you what the error is about.  Does the database still exist? is the first question I'd ask.  SharePoint not having permissions to the database could be another cause.  Removing it from CA can also be done by clicking the database and using the remove option.  PowerShell is an alternate way to do this as well.