# SharePoint2016: Content Database in "Error" status, do not appear with Get-SPContentDatabase

Tags: 2016, error, content-database, sql, status

I am stuck with this urgent issue, same as [Harris' issue here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/279895/38609).

In Central Administration, under "Manage Content Databases", for my main WebApplication, here is the two content databases I have for my main WebApp *(there is another one for the MySite WebApp, but I do not show it, it is irrelevant)*

[image: CentralAdministration displays 2 SPContentDatabases for my main WebApp]

And what's more is that the Database "WSS_Content" has the status "Error".

Now, when running `Get-SPContentDatabase`, here is the result :

[image: result of commandlet Get-SPContentDatabase]

As you can see, I get WSS_Content_002 and WSS_Content_france_MySite, which is the database for MySite WebApp.
I am missing a SP Content Database here !

As said in comment of Harris question, I checked that the database is still existing under my SQL Server :
It is !

By checking under my SQL Server > Disk X > MySQLInstance > DATA :

[image: under sql server files, database exists]

I can see all the Content Databases listed under the Central Administration

I think this database's error status is related to the fact that my users meet issues uploading items.

So, I don't know why I have issues, what is the exact error... could you help me with that please ?
Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the status

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase <error'ed db name>

$db.Status
```

Set it to start if it is not Online:

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase <error'ed db name>

$db.Status = "Online"

$db.Update()
```